# Unable to connect to Neo4j Community Server via Spark Shell : The client is unauthorized due to authentication failure

Tags: apache-spark, neo4j, apache-spark-sql, cypher

**Versions**

**Spark:**: 2.4.0

**Neo4j:**: Neo4j Community Version 3.5.6

**Problem Statement:**

I am trying to connect spark shell  with the Neo4j Community server. Everything is being run locally. The end goal that I am trying to achieve is that I want to query the Neo4j and load the data in the form of rdds. Later on I want to convert these rdds to Json Structure. I am using this connector https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-spark-connector

But at the moment I am facing authentication Problems with the Neo4j Server. When I execute basic commands to make connection and set the Neo4j context. They seems to work fine but when I try to run ***rdd.count*** or ***rdd.first.schema.fieldName*** I run into authentication errors that client is not authenticated.

**Spark Shell Commands:**

```
spark-shell --master spark://10.62.10.71:7077  --conf spark.neo4j.bolt.username=neo4j spark.neo4j.bolt.password=<password> --jars ‪C:/Users/khalid-admin/Desktop/jar_files/neo4j-spark-connector-full-2.4.0-M6
import org.neo4j.spark._

val neo = Neo4j(sc)

val rdd = neo.cypher("MATCH (n:Person) RETURN id(n) as id ").loadRowRdd
```

**Image:**
[image]

**Error:**

```
[Stage 0:>                                                          (0 + 1) / 1]2019-08-22 00:25:17 WARN  TaskSetManager:66 - Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, 10.62.10.71, executor 0): org.neo4j.driver.v1.exceptions.AuthenticationException: The client is unauthorized due to authentication failure.
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.util.Futures.blockingGet(Futures.java:122)
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.DriverFactory.verifyConnectivity(DriverFactory.java:346)
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.DriverFactory.newInstance(DriverFactory.java:93)
        at org.neo4j.driver.v1.GraphDatabase.driver(GraphDatabase.java:136)
        at org.neo4j.driver.v1.GraphDatabase.driver(GraphDatabase.java:119)
        at org.neo4j.spark.Neo4jConfig.driver(Neo4jConfig.scala:15)
        at org.neo4j.spark.Neo4jConfig.driver(Neo4jConfig.scala:19)
        at org.neo4j.spark.Executor$.execute(Neo4j.scala:394)
        at org.neo4j.spark.Neo4jRDD.compute(Neo4j.scala:458)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:402)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:408)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
        Suppresse
```

**Steps Tried so far:**

So far I have tried the following steps:

- I have made sure that I am not using default credentials of the
  Neo4j.
- When I first login in the Neo4j Browser, It prompted me for
  a Change Password window and I changed my password. Everything else seems to be working fine.

Can anybody guide what further steps I can take to narrow down the problem?